What are the best anchors I can use to wall mount an X95K (32.1kg, 70lb) television to a solid limestone fireplace?
I mounted this with the anchors that came with the articulating wall mount that's rated for this TV, but I noticed they started sliding out of the holes after about an hour.


Anchors Pulled Out
Holes
What are some anchors I can use that 100% guarantee that this won't happen again? Ideally they would still be removable solutions, but if that sacrifices safety then I'm willing to use a more permanent anchor. Any professionals here that do this all of the time?
My first thought is to obviously add a lot more holes and use thicker bolts. Are knurled steel anchors a better way to go with this setup?
https://www.amazon.com/Premium-Plated-Carbon-Knurled-BCP1003/dp/B084BVYMMD/
Edit: This is very thick limestone, not a facade. Each hole took about 15-20 minutes to drill. It's a metal fireplace that is enclosed in stone. There is a ~5" wall on each side that aligns with the center and the limestone sticks out about 10"-12" on each side.

Do you know how thick the stone is? If it’s thin, do you know what’s behind it? Without that information, everybody is reduced to guesses that might end badly.

Plastic anchors are not suitable for this purpose.  I'm wondering if lag anchors would be better.  Or maybe the stone is too friable.

@AloysiusDefenestrate This is very thick limestone, not a facade. Each hole took about 15-20 minutes to drill. It's a metal fireplace that is enclosed in stone. There is a ~5" wall on each side that aligns with the center and the limestone sticks out about 10"-12" on each side. There is no way to drill through and bolt it to the other side of the stone, which I think is what you're hinting at.

How deep are the holes you drilled? How long are the anchors and how long are the screws that pulled out?

I would use lead anchors due to the stone and with the load the anchors will be under. I have used lead anchors for this type of application several times with no issues, they tend to conform to the hole that's drilled and allows for some flexibility with no worry of anchor pulling out of the stone. I would also use a little dab of some kind of strong adhesive to give you peace of mind if you're using a tilt or cantilever mount. I hope this helps and it's not permanent so if you decide to take it down just drill out the lead a patch holes accordingly

Lead is soft enough to not fracture the limestone, but has a high enough coefficient of friction that the anchor fully resists the pull-out force of the load. Possibly some types of plastic anchor might perform as well as lead, but other types of plastic anchor would slip out.

You said it better than I could Jim Stewart.

So basically these guys? Hillman Fastener 370249 Lead Anchor, 10-14x1-1/2 https://a.co/d/bNepuMo. I need a 10mm x 60mm version.

They will do the job.

the anchors you are using are not suited for limestone, as you can see they did not even open as they should. the limestone is probably 1/2 or 3/4 inch thick, and the anchor has not grip
you will have better luck with the Premium Zinc Plated Carbon Steel Knurled Drop in Anchor but those might be to long

Yeah,  I picked random ones just for reference. Definitely not the size I need. Thank you. Are knurled the best approach though?
